# How to efficiently set Cursor for an NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, nsview

I have an NSView that is drawing a collection of irregularly shaped (and overlapping) application managed objects: that obviously can't be described by efficiently using non overlapping rectangles.

I want to change the cursor when it it over one of these objects. 
The usual method seems to be to set up tracking rects in response to `-(void)resetCursorRects`, each associated with a different cursor, but I can't apply that to this situation.

I only know which object is top most under the cursor when processing `-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent` messages... so I need to change the cursor then.

Is this appropriate? When is NSView going to try and set the cursor to the usual arrow? I don't want to end up with a flickering cursor because NSView is setting it to default on a different message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using tracking *areas*: [Using Tracking-Area Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html). Particularly, NSTrackingCursorUpdate. This way, you can respond specifically to the individual types of tracking events. I think this helps avoid the situation you described.